# Confused about a theorem on the existence of a fundamental set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My book contains a theorem which states:
"There exists a fundamental set of solutions for the homogenous linear nth order differential equation on an interval I".

Does this mean a homogenous linear differential equation always has a fundamental set of solutions?

Comment: To me, the second statement is a more colloquial reformulation of the first (or perhaps there are some niceties which I, not being a native English speaker, cannot grasp).

Comment: Yes. That is what it means. It always has $n$ linearly independent solutions that provide a basis in the space of solutions.